# When i launch my personalized exception in java why the parser doesn't follow the order of my code?

Tags: java

With this code:

```
class SimpleException extends Exception {}

public class SimpleExceptionDemo {

  public void f() throws SimpleException {
    System.out.println("Throw SimpleException from f()");
    throw new SimpleException();
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleExceptionDemo sed = new SimpleExceptionDemo();
    try {
      sed.f();
    } catch(SimpleException e) {
      System.err.println("Caught it!");
    }

  }
}
```

In some case i have this output:

```
Caught it!
Throw SimpleException from f()
```

Do you know why "Throw SimpleException from f()" is printed after "caught it"?

Comment: You also see this with convertional error messages, eg a null pointer exception's stack trace can be interleaved with things you sent to System.out lines earlier

Comment: Terminology please. 'Throw', not 'launch'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are printing on two different output streams:

```
System.out.println("Throw SimpleException from f()");
```

and

```
System.err.println("Caught it!");
```

The order of the messages appearing from the two different streams is not guaranteed... Use the same stream, and it will be OK.

If you're interested in such issues, it might be interesting to read up on

- [Happened-before](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happened-before)
- [Java memory model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Memory_Model)
- [JCIP: Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/)

Answer (score 7):

`System.err` and `System.out` are different streams, thus the one's output may appear before the other.

If you were to only use one, it would be in the correct order.

Answer (score 2):

You are printing your exception to `System.err` stream. The rest of your output goes to `System.out`. These two are different system streams each with it's own buffers and timing, but, by default, with common receiving end - the console.

The thing is, that buffers in those two streams aren't synchronized, so there is no guarantee, that those two will output in your specified order.

You can force the streams to output immediately by calling `flush()` after the print.

Answer (score 1):

because you are writing into two different streams - System.out and System.Err. Write both into same, then you will get in the order you wanted.